# Use character code in regex for JS with slashes notation

Tags: javascript

I can replace a character in JS with this code:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('\u{92}', 'g'), `'`);
```

But it does not work with the "slashes" notation:

```
str = str.replace(/\u{92}/g, `'`);
```

I mean, nothing is replaced. Did I miss something?

Comment: The `{xx}` Unicode escape is not standard (yet). In regular expressions, the numeric value has to be four or five digits and the `u` flag must be set (in addition to `g` or any other flag you want. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about standardization in the regex syntax; the `{nn}` is marked as "experimental" in the MDN docs for string constants.

Comment: There's an erroneous ) after the /g in   « str = str.replace(/\u{92}/g   `)`, "'"); »

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierVares Thanks, fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(From Pointy comments)  :

```
str = str.replace(/\u0092/g, `'`);
```

works.